# How I get calling a phone number in Cordova platform?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Which plugin is supported to get calling number find out in Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

If you looking for the incoming call, this is not possible at all on iOS due the each app being sandboxed.

On Android you would need to create your own plugin or modify an existing one.

Here's one that listens for incoming calls:

https://github.com/devgeeks/PhoneListener

**Original**

Assuming you mean you want to get the phone number of the device, you can use this plugin.

https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim/blob/master/README.md

Installation:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sim
```

Sample Usage:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
      window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(successCallback, errorCallback);
}

function successCallback(result) {
      console.log(result);
}

function errorCallback(error) {
      console.log(error);
}

// Android only: check permission
function hasReadPermission() {

window.plugins.sim.hasReadPermission(successCallback, errorCallback);
}

// Android only: request permission
function requestReadPermission() {

    window.plugins.sim.requestReadPermission(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

Comment: No, my requirement is whom to calling my number.

Comment: Edited my answer to explain about receiving incoming call information.

Comment: Thank you @L Balsdon. I got your solution from your answer.